# A question about « X est en lien avec Y. » and « X a relation avec Y. »

Tags: constructions

I would like to know

1. if **« X est en lien avec Y. »** equals **« X est en rapport/relation avec Y. »** ?

and

2. if **« X a relation avec Y. »** equals **« X a lien/rapport avec Y. »** ?

As this is a simple question, a simple yes or no is all I need.

X and Y could represent anything i.e. people, places, actions and inanimate objects.

Comment: What are X and Y ? Concepts ? People ? Physical quantities ? Or would you like an answer to cover all cases ? (because lien / rapport / relation do not mean the same thing when applied to people)

Comment: In order to make this question answerable, can you please clarify what X and Y can refer to in this context?

Answer (score 0):

**I**

The meaning of "*en lien*" is not always the same as that of "*en relation*". Here is an excellent article dedicated to the locution "en lien" which gives examples of the several meanings, thus allowing to make out better when the meaning is synonymous to "en relation".

From the *[OQLF](http://204.19.47.207/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5273)*

> - Les suspects ont été inculpés **en lien** avec les récents attentats. (ou : relativement à, **en relation** avec)
> - Les directeurs de l’agence sont en lien avec le siège social. (ou : en liaison avec)
> - Beaucoup d’employés, même en vacances, restent en lien avec le bureau. (ou : en liaison avec, en contact avec)
> - Pour être reconnus, les cours suivis doivent être en lien étroit avec le domaine d’études de l’étudiant. (ou : étroitement liés à)
> - La priorité est de créer un office national qui coordonne la recherche, en lien avec les organismes déjà existants. (ou : en liaison avec, en collaboration avec)
> - Ses problèmes de dépendance pourraient-ils être **en lien** avec la forte pression qu’il subit au travail? (ou : être liés à)
> - Un domaine de recherche qui étudie l’humain **en lien** avec son environnement. (ou : dans son rapport avec)

**II**

"X a relation avec Y." and "X a lien/rapport avec Y." are not correct. What you are most likely to write is « **X a une relation avec Y.** » and « **X a un lien/rapport avec Y.** »

"Avoir une relation avec" is synonymous to "avoir  un rapport avec". ([internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/11791/avoir-un-rapport/))

As "avoir un lien avec" is synonymous with "avoir un rapport avec", then the answer is yes.

#### *Complement suggested by **[user Noybwbh](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43434/a-question-about-x-est-en-lien-avec-y-and-x-a-relation-avec-y/43435?noredirect=1#comment88167_43435)***

Apparently all combinations of entities are possible and this makes sense since there are ties from objects and creatures to both objects and creatures.
I rounded up a few examples.

1/ réf. : first example above —  L'inculpation est en rapport avec les attentats. (non human, non human)
2/ [réf.1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1Xz9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&dq=%22est+en+rapport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit9-uz_drsAhUH3aQKHU-CAM0Q6AEwCnoECB8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22est%20en%20rapport%22&f=false) Si le judo s'est popularisé, c'est en rapport avec l'expansion du Japon comme puissance économique. (*non human entity (c = "popularisation du judo), non human entity (expansion du Japon)*)

3/ [réf.2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rqg9AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22est+en+rapport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit9-uz_drsAhUH3aQKHU-CAM0Q6AEwC3oECCAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22est%20en%20rapport%22&f=false) Plus un Être est vivant et plus il est en rapport avec les objets hors de lui (*human being or animal or other creature, object*)

4/ [réf.3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fwJGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA317&dq=%22est+en+rapport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit9-uz_drsAhUH3aQKHU-CAM0Q6AEwSnoECBkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22est%20en%20rapport%22&f=false) Il est donc certain que le principe le plus chéri d'Aristote , s'il est en rapport avec l'homme sensuel de l'antiquité , n'est pas en rapport avec notre nature considérée dans sa véritable intégralité , dans sa véritable grandeur. (*principle, human being*)
5/ [réf.4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=g98EsY-TZIgC&pg=PA505&dq=%22est+en+rapport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit9-uz_drsAhUH3aQKHU-CAM0Q6AEwTHoECBsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22est%20en%20rapport%22&f=false) Or , l'homme est en rapport avec ses semblables et avec Dieu . (*human being, human being/god*)

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I read the article using Google Translate (lol ) and I’m left with question, which I’m struggling to answer, what does **X** and **Y** have to be in order for **« X est en lien avec Y. »** to equal **« X est en rapport/relation avec Y. »** ? Do you happen to know? 

Comment: Thank you so much the “complement” you added above!  I don’t completely understand the first paragraph of it however. Are you saying that actually **X** and ***Y** can be anything for **« X est en lien avec Y. »** to equal **« X est en rapport/relation avec Y. »** ?

Comment: @Noybwbh Yes, that's pretty much what you can deduce from this page: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22est%20en%20lien%20avec%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr. Take a long look at it and see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

First, as pointed out by LPH in his answer, the formulations « X a relation avec Y. » and « X a lien/rapport avec Y. » are slightly unusual and outdated. The other formulations « X est en lien avec Y. » and « X est en rapport/relation avec Y. » are much more common.

Second, while there is a tiny difference between "en lien" and "en rapport", this difference is so tiny that 95% of French speakers do not make the difference, and in 95% of cases you can use both. In all the examples given by LPH in his answer, both expressions are working. For instance:

- "*Un domaine de recherche qui étudie l’humain **en lien** avec son environnement.*" is the same as "***en rapport** avec son environnement.*" or "***en relation** avec son environnement.*" (although the purists may prefer "*en relation **à** son environnement.*" in this latter case).